# Elasticsearch, how to calculate cumulative probability of normal distribution?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose, each document has the following data:

```json
{
  //some_other_fields,
  "seasonal_data": [
    {
      "day_of_year": 1,
      "sales": 3
    },
    {
      "day_of_year": 2,
      "sales": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

When ranking documents, I want to consider seasonal score along with others.

For a given `day_of_year`, I'll consider 7 days (including 3 days prior, 3 days after).
I'll get average sales value of seven days.

We assume sales data follows a normal distribution:

```
seasonal_score = p-value(avg_sales_7days)
```

How can this be done in Elasticsearch?

Comment: It could probably be done using scripts, but searches would be slow. I'd suggest pre-computing average at ingestion time for each day.

Comment: @eugene Can you provide a concrete expected result + the values the result has been calculated on? Also, is `seasonal_data` of type `nested` like we discussed yday?